# Greater than and Less than sub query in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDB, let say one collection student is having age and height and other details. in the other collection let say filter we have age and height only. I have to find all the student where age is greater than age in filter collection. I think this can be done using sub query, but I don't know that how sub query will work for greater than and less than in MongoDB. Can any one help?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? In this case, are you sure Mongo is the best database product for the job, this sounds like traditional relational stuff to me.

Comment: ok, but we have more than 300 gb of data so can we do it in relational database. I think query execution will take a huge amount of time in relational database. Can you please suggest any relational database where we can do it?

Comment: PostgreSQL could handle that easily. You have have to have proper indexing. I suppose this could still be done on Mongo, but how big is each collection per student?

Comment: student collection is 280 gb,

Comment: it would be good if we can do it in mongodb as i have already impported data in mangodb.

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything with Mongo, but yeah, it's certainly possible, I just don't recall how.